# read multiple excel file and apply process on it using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

i have multiple excel files in D:\ directory these files name starting with "gt" characters i need to delete all empty rows in these files in , Sheet1 only and store processed files in other names  ,

Q :\ The following code has been successfully deleted all empty rows but from single file , how we can applied it to all files in D:\ directory and their names start with "gt" characters ?

the following code which i mention above ...

```
[~, ~, data] = xlsread('D:\gt1.xls','Sheet1');
data(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x), data)) = {''};
ii = 1;
while true
    try
        if any(strcmp('', data(ii,:)))  % find rows with empty cell
            data(ii,:) = [];               % remove the row
        else
            ii = ii+1;
        end
    catch
        break  % When the process goes beyond the end, stop the loop.
    end
end
xlswrite('D:\result1.xls', data)
```

**and i tried this code long time for all excel file**

```
FileNames=dir('D:\gt*.xls');
for i=1:length(FileNames)
FileToLoad=FileNames(i).name;
[~, ~, data] = xlsread(FileToLoad,'Sheet1');
data(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x), data)) = {''};
ii = 1;
while true
try
if any(strcmp('', data(ii,:)))  % find rows with empty cell
data(ii,:) = [];               % remove the row
else
ii = ii+1;
end
catch
break  % When the process goes beyond the end, stop the loop.
end
end
xlswrite('D:\result[ii].xls', data)
end
```

hope to get output like

```
    gt1.xls file store as result1.xls file ;
    gt2.xls file store as result2.xls file ;
    and so on ....
```

Comment: Start with `dir('gt*.xls')`

Comment: thanks for reply ,,, what i have to modify to read and apply above code over all my excel files that start with gt* characters ,, please any help .